# How to check for valid oracle table name using sql/plsql

Tags: oracle

I need to check if a string contains a valid Oracle table name using sql/plsql. The criteria I found for a Oracle table name are these:

1. The table name must begin with a letter.
2. The table name can not be longer than 30 characters.
3. The table name must be made up of alphanumeric characters or the following special characters: $, _, and #.
4. The table name can not be a reserved word.

Criteria 1,2,3 don't seem so hard to tackle. But what about point 4? What are my options without trying to actually create a table with the given name and then see if it succeeds or fails.

Comment: The rules are a little more complicated than rules 1-3, you can have nearly any string for a table as long as it is enclosed by double quotes (you can create a table with non-ASCII characters).
You should use dbms_assert as suggested by Jim Hudson in place of rules 1-3 (in addition to check for reserved words).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle has a built-in that's useful for checking whether a SQL Name is valid. That's especially useful when building dynamic queries where you need to prevent SQL Injection.

Check out the **dbms_assert.simple_sql_name** built-in, and see the Oracle white paper at [How to Write Injection Proof PL/SQL](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/pl_sql/pdf/how_to_write_injection_proof_plsql.pdf) for more details.

v$reserved_words is also useful, as others have noted.

Comment: +1 For suggesting to use a builtin. Note that dbms_assert is only available in Oracle11.

Comment: Hi Rob, apparently the package was backported to all versions of Oracle (down to 8.1.7.4) in a patch in 2005 (to deal with SQL injection threats). It is definetely available on a new 10gR2 instance while at the same time absent from the 10gr2 doc. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

For SQL reserved words you can check v$reserved_words. Here the [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2048.htm#REFRN30204) from the documentation

Comment: Sucks that in Oracle 9i this view contains only KEYWORD and LENGTH.

Answer (score 0):

I have a SQL_RESERVED_WORDS table that I check against.

EDIT:

(I lied... it was just a SYNONYMN for the table in carpenteri's post)

Answer (score 0):

It is a fairly large [list](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) to check.  Can you simply add a default prefix to the tables and avoid these problems all together?  user_xxx